# Seeking add-on for notes

Tags: modeling, add-on

I often wish there were an add-on to embed notes in a blender design, tacked to specific points in the model of an object. I mostly do 3D models for mechanical designs that get 3D printed, and sometimes for things that get built the old-fashioned way (cut, join, glue etc).

I would expect notes like that to behave like the "Grease Pencil" or "Ruler/Protractor" tools do now. Not physical objects, but like an info layer.

As a design evolves, many features have reasons for being as they are that may not be obvious so I need to make notes elsewhere, in a separate file.
"The flange needs to be 1cm wider near the bolt" or "Don't reduce the overlap to less than 1mm near the left side."

Those sort of spatial notes would be great embedded if I could attach them to the geometry directly, so I'd see visually why I did a thing, or changed something.

Also would be great for revisions - "previously tried at 1cm, need at least 2cm here."  This would reduce risk of repeating past mistakes.

Anyway - searched for such an add-on but haven't found anything. Anyone know of something like that?

Comment: Don't know of anything like that off hand. If you can't find anything, I'd be happy to quote on building it for you. You can contact me at todd@resonancemedia.ca.

Comment: You can use Grease pencil, created separately for object, with *Stroke Placement* option set to *Surface*. Then the text will be snapped to the mesh surface and it'll be seen only if that mesh is selected (if you haven't tried already).